# Local P2P Library/Protocol

Tags: linux, p2p, broadcast, multicast, lan

Can anyone recommend a LOCAL P2P library or protocol for linux?

I'm looking for P2P solution limited to a LAN for distributing a single file (5-300M) that I periodically update in my app. I'm trying to avoid upsteam internet use, minimize retransmissions of the same data on the local network as much as possible, and avoid any user configuration.

Various sites range between 2 and 5000 clients that need to participate in the sharing, and some of the networks are corporate. Many users are wireless and will drop on/off the network randomly. Any client can become a seed by downloading the data from a remote web server, but I'm trying to minimize the number of clients who do so (to minimize client upstream bandwidth, not for my server).

I can build a solution for this myself, but would rather reuse an existing library/protocol if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/) and [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/)